# Unable to filter on the Boolean field in SP 2013 REST service

Tags: rest, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I am trying to filter the result in the SP 2013 rest service but I am getting the below response -

> Error - No property 'test' exists in type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity' at position 0.

When I take off the filter, I do see the TEST field is coming in the response -

REST Service:

```
SPsite.com/sites/events/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Events?$filter=test+eq+1
```

RESET response without filter -

```
 <d:ActiveEventsS>Yes</d:ActiveEventsS>
    <d:Test m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
    <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `SPSite.com/sites/events/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Events')/items?$filter=test eq 1` the listdata.svc is for sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

listdata.svc is SharePoint 2010 method for getting data from SharePoint list using REST API.

You can use "_api/web/lists" method for getting data from SharePoint List using REST API in SharePoint 2013.

**End Point URL:** `SPsite.com/sites/events/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Events')/items?$filter=Test eq 1`